# left click to activate onclick and right click to activate href

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, css, onclick

I have an img tag as(which of course is not of the exact syntax)

`<img src="http://localhost/img/img_1.png" id=1 onclick="say_hi(id)" href="/img_page_1/" alt="Aim Pic"  width="230" height= "164"  />`

what i need here is when user left clicks on img, i need onClick to be triggered and when user right clicks on it, it must act like a general href showing option ("open in new window" etc)

why i need it is, i want to show the page preview related to image with in the home page by bluring rest of page(ajax is used here to load preview of image page in say_hi function) and when user right clicks on it i want it to feel like a normal href so that he can directly open the page in other tab rather than a preview.

EDIT:
In simple terms i want to state/write/give a link to some image which acts normally as a link when right clicked(showing the context menu which has all the options for a link) but it must trigger a onClick event(or run a function in javascript) when left clicked.

Thank you.

Comment: `href` isn't a valid attribute of the `img` tag

Comment: also: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Removed previous answer in reply to question edit.*

---

The new edit is much simpler, see the following (using inline-JavaScript as an example - it's bad practice and shouldn't be used in any production code - see **[here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting)** and [**here**](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/) for more info.):

**HTML/Inline-JS:**

```
<a href="/img_page_1/" onclick="left_click(id)">
  <img src="http://localhost/img/img_1.png">
</a>
```

Firstly, `href` isn't a valid attribute on images - give it to an anchor (`<a>`), which you can then wrap around the image.

Only the left-click will trigger your function, right click still has default behaviour.

**Function:**

```
function left_click(id) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default anchor action.
  // Rest of your function here.
}
```

Here we prevent the default behaviour triggered by the anchor - stopping the link from taking you to a different page.

[**jsFiddle example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hXDN9/6/)

Comment: thank you for the reply, here i dont want to do anything when user clicks on the element i just want browser to show options like open in new tab etc which are generally shown when href is used but in my situation i can not see open in new tab option i can just see as if i'm right clicking on a normal image(only open image in new tab and few ither image related things).
i hope i'm little more clear now.

Comment: yes indeed, i want it to trigger in some way or the other,
in simple terms i want a function to be run when left clicked and when right clicked it must act as if i right clicked on a link.

Comment: @MohanKrishna Yes, I said in my answer you just have to adapt it to your case. Did you not check my jsFiddle?

Comment: so the thing which i'm looking for is event.preventDefault();
I tried the same thing which you stated in the above comment but didnot use  event.preventDefault(); so it was was triggering onclick event but at the same time even navigating, so it looked as if it was just navigating rather than triggering onclick event on left click.
Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @MohanKrishna I can't even remember what my comment said haha :/ glad to help anyway

Comment: you introduced me to event.preventDefault() which saved my day,
thank you :)

Comment: can you please state what exactly is a bad practice in that solution and why is that so..? thank you.

Comment: @MohanKrishna Sure I included two links for you, really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to differentiate between mouse buttons through the [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.button) member of the event object:

```
var left, right;
left = mie ? 1 : 0;
right = 2;

var clickHandler = function (e){
    if(e.button === left){
       // do onClick stuff and return
    }
    else if(e.button === right){
       // show your context menu
    }
}, false);
```

But this does look like you could simply have your link as `<a href="" onClick="clickHandler">description</a>` if I'm not misunderstanding what you want to do.